# jQuery .stopImmediatePropagation(); won't work on external JS file

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax form I don't want to be submitted and when I use the code below in my main.js file, it doesn't prevent the action. What annoys me is when I take the **exact** same code and place it in `<script>` tags, it works fine. Why would this do this. Just so you know, the page with the form I want to block is loaded via jQuery's ajax `.load()` function. Could that be a reason? Thanks for the help!

---

Heres the code:

```
$('.searchPageForm').submit(function(b) {
    b.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log("Form Submitted");
    console.log("App Version: VGxLEM8pZoJGK"); 
    return false;
});
```

Comment: If the above is in an external file that is included in the head section then it will be executed_before_ the form in question exists and thus the handler won't bind to anything. You need to either run it _after_ the form has been loaded or use a delegated event handler (assuming delegation works on the submit event).

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll add a bind event through the callback function of `.load`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form is loaded dynamically, you either need to bind the submit handler after the form has been inserted into the call (ie, call it in the ajax complete function), or use a live event hander like `.on()`, like so:

```
$('.searchPageForm').on('submit', function(b) {
    b.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log("Form Submitted");
    console.log("App Version: VGxLEM8pZoJGK"); 
    return false;
});
```